# Python Tkinter - Unable to get value from Class (tk.Frame) Combobox

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, tkinter, return

I am using a Class to create a number of `LabelledComboBoxes`, display the box and label, then return the value from the `ComboBox` to another function within the Class. This part works.

The problem is when I try and use this same value elsewhere. I cannot construct the correct code to pull out this `combobox` value and name. I understand that I can use global variables to accomplish this but would prefer to avoid this if possible.

Any other questions on this topic do not show where the Class has tk.Frame.

`LabeledCombobox6(tk.Frame).combo6.get()` or other combinations only throw up errors.

In Summary: I want to return and use each `combobox` value and name from its Class in another function (not associated with that `combobox` Class). Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class LabeledCombobox6(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, dictionary, *args, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kw)
        self.dictionary = dictionary
        self.combo6 = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.combo6 = ttk.Combobox(self, width=20, values=my_list, name="combo6")
        self.combo6.current(0)
        self.combo6.pack(fill="both")
        self.combo6.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.on_selection)
        self.label6 = tk.Label(self, width=20, bg="light blue", text=f"\nCombo Name: \n\nCombo Value: \n\n")
        self.label6.pack(fill="both", expand=False)

    def return_value(self):
        return self.combo6.get()

    def on_selection(self, event):
        # updates combo label with details of current item selected
        c_name = event.widget
        self.s_value = self.combo6.get()
        self.label6.config(bg="light yellow", text=(f"\n\nCombo Name:\n {c_name}\n\nCombo Value: \n{self.s_value}\n\n"))

def selector_gui():
        self.combo6 = LabeledCombobox6(root, my_list)
        self.combo6.pack(side="left")
        # all other combobox widgets will also go here

def display_values():
    # get combo names and values from Classes above
    x = combo6.return_value()

    calc_label = tk.Label(root, width=40, height=5, bg="green", text=(f"combo6 - {x}"))
    calc_label.pack(side="right")

def calculate():
    # User will press button when selections from all comboboxes have been made
    flip_flac_card_button=ttk.Button(root, width=15, text="Calculate Now", command=display_values)
    flip_flac_card_button.pack(side="left")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x300")
    my_list = ["1", "5", "8"]
    

    selector_gui()
    calculate()

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `combo6.return_value()` and `combo7.return_value()` to get the two values selected in the comboboxes.  What is the point of getting the *internal names* of the two comboboxes?

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for your response and have amended the code. If Combo6 is now in a Class how do I access its value from outside the class. [As a beginner its unbelievably frustrating].

Comment: You should not create another instance of `SelectGUI()` inside `display_values()`.  Use the one created in main block.

Comment: @acw1668 I wanted to answer your second question separately re getting the names of internal names of comboboxes. My initial thought was to display the output dynamically, however, in hindsight I will display output sequentially in a table format which makes much more sense to be honest i.e. combo1_output, combo2_output..etc.

Comment: @acw1668 I see what you mean and have fixed that. Can you tell me how I access the combo6.return_value() - that just doesn't work nor does LabeledCombobox6().combo6.return_value().  Just cannot see how to return the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use class and instance variables instead of functions because local variable defined in one function cannot be accessed in other functions.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class LabeledCombobox6(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, my_list, *args, **kw): # changed argument dictionary to my_list
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kw)
        self.combo6 = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.combo6 = ttk.Combobox(self, width=20, values=my_list, name="combo6")
        self.combo6.current(0)
        self.combo6.pack(fill="both")
        self.combo6.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.on_selection)
        self.label6 = tk.Label(self, width=20, bg="light blue", text=f"\nCombo Name: \n\nCombo Value: \n\n")
        self.label6.pack(fill="both", expand=False)

    def return_value(self):
        return self.combo6.get()

    def on_selection(self, event):
        # updates combo label with details of current item selected
        c_name = event.widget
        self.s_value = self.combo6.get()
        self.label6.config(bg="light yellow", text=(f"\n\nCombo Name:\n {c_name}\n\nCombo Value: \n{self.s_value}\n\n"))

class SelectorGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("1000x300")
        my_list = ["1", "5", "8"]

        self.combo6 = LabeledCombobox6(self, my_list)
        self.combo6.pack(side="left")
        # all other combobox widgets will also go here

        # create the result label
        self.calc_label = tk.Label(self, width=40, height=5, bg="green")
        self.calc_label.pack(side="right")

        # User will press button when selections from all comboboxes have been made
        flip_flac_card_button=ttk.Button(self, width=15, text="Calculate Now", command=self.display_values)
        flip_flac_card_button.pack(side="left")

    def display_values(self):
        # get combo names and values from Classes above
        x = self.combo6.return_value()
        self.calc_label.config(text=f"combo6 - {x}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SelectorGUI().mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for your help, genuinely appreciated. This is an area I need to get my head round and practice more. Cheers Boon.